# Alignment issue in the unanswered tab

Tags: bug, design, unanswered-questions

There is an alignment issue in the [unaswered questions](https://photo.stackexchange.com/unanswered) tab.

Some extra space is displaying in between the tabs and questions section.

Where as the extra space is not displaying in the [questions](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions) tab or any other Stack Exchange site.

**Screenshot for reference:**

[image: Extra space]

Inspect an element of the extra space, seeing that the issue was happened due to the CSS class `.subheader { margin-bottom: 10px;`